# Rails 3 Validation with Scope Conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have an invoice model with approver_note, po_number and state_id.

I need validations to check:

```
validates :approver_note, :presence => true, {:scope => state_id == 3}
validates :po_number, :presence => true, {:scope => state_id ==2}
```

So, if the user selects state_id = 3, he must enter a note.
If he selects state_id = 2, he must enter a po_number.

Any assistance would be great... thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for the `:if` option instead of `:scope`.

```
validates :approver_note, :presence => true,
  :if => lambda { |invoice| invoice.state_id == 3 }
```

But since a lambda is a little ugly, I'd probably add a method to encapsulate what you're doing a bit better:

```
validates :approver_note, :presence => true, :if => :requires_note?
validates :po_number, :presence => true, :if => requires_po_number?

def requires_note?
  state_id == 3
end

def requires_po_number?
  state_id == 2
end
```

If you actually have a bunch of different attributes that are required when `state_id` is 3, not just a note, then you may want something like this:

```
validates :approver_note, :presence => true, :if => :green_state?
validates :po_number, :presence => true, :if => orange_state?

def green_state?
  state_id == 3
end

def orange_state?
  state_id == 2
end
```

(Replace "green" with -- I dunno -- "high_documentation" or whatever makes sense in your world.)

Or maybe you want to let the state decide what it is:

```
def green_state?
  state.green?
end
```

It really does help to make the terminology in your code adhere more closely to your real-world language, as opposed to "3" and "2".

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  I used your second option, as I don't like lambdas either.   However, even though I get the correct validation error messages, the record is still updated.  In other words, when the user selects Approve (state_id = 2), without entering a po_number, I get an error displayed, but the record is still updated to invoice.state_id = 2...   ??

Comment: Hmm, that sounds like a separate issue, probably in your controller. If validation fails, an ActiveRecord won't be saved. You may want to post that as another question, and include your controller action.

Comment: Thanks for the idea on using friendlier terminology - I will definitely do that.  Ok, I'll take a closer look and post another question.  Thanks again!