# Single Table Inheritance with validation ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

If I have models like this:

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord
    # create table called transactions and add type column to it.  
    # add common methods inside this class
end

class CashTransaction < Transaction
     # the type column will be CashTransaction and used to determine entry for this class in transactions table 
end

class CreditCardTransaction < Transaction
    validates :settled, :presence => true
    # the type column will be CreditCardTransaction and used to determine entry for this class in  transactions table 
end
```

How can I apply validation that is unique to the CreditCardTransaction?  So parent class Transaction and CashTransaction do not need validation on whether the transaction was settled?

Comment: Are you on Rails 3 or Rails 4? This question is tagged as both.

Answer (score 2):

Your example code is correct.

In Rails 3, validations called in a subclass will apply to an instance of that subclass only (in addition to superclass validations). Superclass validations apply to all subclasses.

Remember to only work with subclasses when using STI. In other words, *never* instantiate the superclass for any reason. Doing so will interfere with Rails' internal STI magic sauce, leaving you with unexpected behavior and ugly hacks to get things working again.

Answer (score 0):

Hm...I think you have an column indicating that this is `CreditCardTransation`. So you can use validator inside a scope:

[Rails 3 Validation with Scope Conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216441/rails-3-validation-with-scope-conditions)